# How to setup Alby wallet for testnet bitcoins

Tags: wallet, testnet, lightning-network-daemon

I'm trying to test out the Alby wallet. I wanted to test it's working with fake testnet bitcoins (tBTC).
I tried to follow this guide:
https://github.com/getAlby/lightning-browser-extension/wiki/Test-setup
and I've added the following values in alby [`Connect your node` page](https://getalby.com/node)
[image]

but it's not working and giving me an error:

[image]

Please tell me what steps to perform to get testnet coins in Alby wallet for testing and development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to connect testnet node on mainnet. at Alby, we use testnet and regtest network for working on the product (testnet is a private network used for testing sats on testnet nodes that have no value).

You can visit app.regtest.getalby.com to add a new testnet node.

however if you are trying to test the extension,

1. on the welcome page, select connect tab
2. select lnd node as your backend
3. put testnet credentials to add testnet account
4. you can use htlc.me to do exchanges or use different lnd testnet accounts